# Solidedge remote access for only one user: best way?

Tags: opengl, remote-access, cad, xenapp

We plan to give access remotely for one of our users to Solidedge as he is working from home and other users into our offices. Currently, he has is own PC at home and has to come regulary here.

I already tried XenDesktop, XenApp (but not the lastest release at it is not available for demo purposes, only the 6.0 release that I will try today).

Also, regarding XenApp coupled with OpenGL, because of Solidedge, is the setup process 'complex' because I could not find any specific documentation regarding that usage.

The main factor is the bandwidth: XenApp doesn't seems to provide bandwitth compression features like XenDesktop do, that can dicrease the bandwith usage to 2M/Bits: from our LAN, I have doubts it will be usable.

Well, do you see an other easier way to do what I would like to set up?
Could you provide me we some details that could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on Windows I'd suggest simple plain VNC on desktop machine. Yes I know it sounds stupid. For a terminal server kind of access NVidia provides apropriate combinations of hard and software.

On Linux there's another possibility: [Xpra](http://xpra.org). Simply spoken Xpra is a special kind of compositing manager, that uses a different display as the composition surface. It can operate over low bandwidth links by using efficient video codecs for compression. Usually Xpra uses a virtual framebuffer X server to run the clients on. But is can also be used in combination with a X server using a GPU.

However each user uses it's own X server for this. So if the system's GPU is used only one user can use Xpra at a time (actually since the NVidia drivers claim supporting hybrid graphics now, it may be possible to exploit that somehow – I haven't researched into that yet, though).

So the user starts Xpra using

```
xpra --start-child=xterm --vfb=/usr/bin/X start :100
```

And can then connect to the remote machine

```
xpra attach ssh:remote-host:100
```